# I want to get all start up programs from registry can any one help me?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

i tried this code......
`CStringArray csaStartUpProgram;

```
csaStartUpProgram.Add(Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce);

csaStartUpProgram.Add(Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run);

csaStartUpProgram.Add(SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce);

csaStartUpProgram.Add(SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run);

for(int nStartupProgram=0;nStartupProgram<csaStartUpProgram.GetSize();nStartupProgram++)
{



    HKEY hKey;

    if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,csaStartUpProgram[nStartupProgram],&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {

    DWORD dwValues, dwMaxValueNameLen, dwMaxValueLen;
    LONG lRet = ::RegQueryInfoKey(hKey, 
                          NULL, NULL,    // lpClass, lpcClass
                          NULL,          // lpReserved
                          NULL, NULL,    // lpcSubKeys, lpcMaxSubKeyLen
                          NULL,          // lpcMaxClassLen
                          &dwValues,
                          &dwMaxValueNameLen,
                          &dwMaxValueLen,
                          NULL,          // lpcbSecurityDescriptor
                          NULL);         // lpftLastWriteTime
    if(ERROR_SUCCESS == lRet)
    {  
        // allocate enough to fit max. length name and value
        LPTSTR pszName = new TCHAR[dwMaxValueNameLen + 1];
        LPBYTE lpData   = new BYTE[dwMaxValueLen];
        for(DWORD dwIndex = 0; dwIndex < dwValues; dwIndex++)
        {
            DWORD dwNameSize  = dwMaxValueNameLen + 1;
            DWORD dwValueSize = dwMaxValueLen;
            DWORD dwType;
             lRet = ::RegEnumValue(hKey, dwIndex, pszName, &dwNameSize,0, &dwType, lpData, &dwValueSize);
            CString strName = pszName;
            if(REG_SZ == dwType)
            {
                CString strValue = (LPCTSTR)lpData;


            }
        CLog::Log(strName + _T(""));
        }
    delete []pszName;
    delete []lpData;
    }
    }
}`
```

I am getting output:

Communicator,
SAP_WUS_UNT,
BCSSync,
 Communicator,
 SAP_WUS_UNT,
 BCSSync,

Same output is repeating two times but i want all programs from above start up paths please help me...

Comment: I think it is pointing to WoW6432Node Path for Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run path also this may Win32 function pointing to Wow6432Node then how to get the programs from above path.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your program is a Win32 program that you are trying to run on a 64 bit OS. The OS has a special mechanism called [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that allows 32-bit applications to access a separate registry node in 64-bit environment. Basically, every time you open `Software\\Microsoft\\` key the OS redirects you to `Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\` key. Thus, you are reading the same key twice.

In the article at the hyperlink above they say that in order to explicitly access the node for 64-bit applications you need to use this flag: KEY_WOW64_64KEY

> The KEY_WOW64_64KEY and KEY_WOW64_32KEY flags enable explicit access
>   to the 64-bit registry view and the 32-bit view, respectively. For
>   more information, see Accessing an Alternate Registry View.

On a side node, I can't see where you close the HKEY handle. It is always a good idea to close it after you opened it with `RegOpenKey`. Also, use a newer API, `RegOpenKeyEx`.

To open a 64-bit key use this code:

```
::RegOpenKeyEx(
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,                 //_In_        HKEY hKey,
  csaStartUpProgram[nStartupProgram], //_In_opt_    LPCTSTR lpSubKey,
  NULL,                               //_Reserved_  DWORD ulOptions,
  KEY_WOW64_64KEY,                    //_In_        REGSAM samDesired,
  &hKey                               //_Out_       PHKEY phkResult
);
```